# VB NET What is the good way to find a position of an object inside a scrollable panel?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an object inside a scrollable panel, and I want to get the position of the object. Everything is okay until I have create many object inside the panel until the panel needed to be scrolled. Then I notice that the X Position of the object changed after scrolling the panel. Take a look at example image below

[X Position inside a scrollable panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYw4F.jpg)

I'm using Position.X to get a X Position of the object, but as you can see in the picture above. It does me no good.

Is there a way to get the actual position even if the panel is scrolled ?

UPDATE:
I have One Panel that have Auto Scroll as True , and on Button inside a Panel, let's just say the button name is Button1 and the Panel is Panel1

The Code i use to get the location of the Button1 is :

```
Dim msg = Button1.Location.X
msgbox(msg)
```

Comment: WPF? UWP? WinForms? What are you working with here?  Please add it as a tag.

Comment: its WinForms, i have added it for your information

Comment: Behold the secrets of MSDN: **[AutoScrollPosition Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.AutoScrollPosition);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the screen position of the object, I don't know how because you didn't post your code.  What you need to do is add the scroll offset, eg.

```
Position.X + scrollableControl.AutoScrollPosition.X
```

Comment: I got the Minus Value (-) instead of the same value of the object before scrolled

Comment: @hakimhomecent What value are you getting from AutoScrollPosition? Is it negative? If so subtract it.